# Haskell Win32 LPCTSTR IsString Typeclass

Tags: haskell

I'm testing `incline-c` for win32 api.
I realized that `LPCTSTR` doesn't have a `IsString` instance.
But I don't know how to write it.
Any hint?

For information:

```
type LPTSTR = Ptr TCHAR
type TCHAR = CWchar
```

defined in `System.Win32.Types`

and

```
newtype CWchar

Haskell type representing the C wchar_t type.

Constructors
CWchar Int32
```

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.String
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Win32 as CW
import qualified Language.C.Inline as C
import System.Win32.Types

instance IsString LPCTSTR where


C.context CW.win32Ctx

C.include "<windows.h>"

showMsg :: LPCTSTR -> IO INT
showMsg s = do
  [C.exp| INT{ MessageBox( NULL, $(LPCTSTR s), "Haskell Rocks", MB_OK )} |]

main = showMsg "Hello Haskell"
```

Edit:
I've managed to achieve this with ByteString

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Language.C.Inline.Win32 as CW
import qualified Language.C.Inline as C
import System.Win32.Types

C.context (CW.win32Ctx <> C.bsCtx)

C.include "<windows.h>"

showMsg :: BS.ByteString -> IO INT
showMsg s = do
  [C.exp| INT{ MessageBox( NULL, $bs-ptr:s, "Haskell Rocks", MB_OK )} |]

main = showMsg "Hello Haskell"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This instance can't be sensibly defined, for the same reason it can't be done with [CString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Foreign-C-String.html): *pointers to char can't do memory management*. Thus, generating C-strings at runtime would be either unsafe from dangling memory, or incur memory leaks.

What *should* in principle be possible is to nevertheless get access to *string literals*, the same way this is also possible in C itself: by just allocating a static memory location once an *compile time*. But the `IsString` class doesn't support this.

In summary: C-strings are a pain to work with in Haskell, so better only use them directly at the interface to the C code. I.e. if you write even a low-level wrapper around a C function taking a C [w]string, then this should take a `String` or `Text` as the argument. Convert it to the suitable C-string in the IO block right around the C call, and “purify” them together with `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: Thanks. I've just managed to do it with ByteString. I will try your suggestions too